# Receive message with Windows named pipe in Golang and winio

Tags: windows, go, ipc

I'm trying to do some IPC using Windows named pipes using the github.com/Microsoft/go-winio module.

I've been able to create a listener on a named pipe. I'm trying to simply print out the received message but when I read the net.Conn in my handler, I receive 0 bytes / an empty message.

Here's my server code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/Microsoft/go-winio"
)

func printMsgServer(c net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("in the handler")
    log.Printf("Client connected [%s]", c.RemoteAddr().Network())
    
    buf := make([]byte, 512)
    n, err := c.Read(buf)
    fmt.Printf("read %d bytes\n", n);
    if err != nil {
        str := string(buf)
        fmt.Printf("got message: %s\n", str)
    }
}

func main() {
    pipePath := `\\.\pipe\mypipename`

    if err := os.RemoveAll(pipePath); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    pc := &winio.PipeConfig{
        SecurityDescriptor: "D:P(A;;GA;;;AU)",
        InputBufferSize:  512,
        OutputBufferSize: 512,
    }

    l, err := winio.ListenPipe(pipePath, pc)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", err)
    }
    defer l.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("accept error:", err)
        }
        fmt.Println("got a connection - dispatching to handler")
        go printMsgServer(conn)
    }
}
```

And here's the client code I'm using to write a message:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    pipePath := `\\.\pipe\mypipename`
    f, err := os.OpenFile(pipePath, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening file: %v", err)
    }
    f.WriteString("message from client\n")
    f.Close()
    fmt.Println("done writing to pipe")
}
```

I first start the server, then run the client. The server output is:

```
in the handler
2022/02/20 16:41:40 Client connected [pipe]
read 0 bytes
got message:
```

Any idea why I'm getting 0 bytes / an empty message?

Also, is the way that I'm writing to the named pipe correct? I was expecting to use net.Dial, like in equivalent code for a Unix Domain Socket. I'm not used to Windows named pipes, but from what I can tell, writing to it like it's a file as I have done might be right, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues in your code.

- A pipe doesn't support `O_APPEND` mode. That is what causes `f.WriteString` to fail (and write 0 bytes to the pipe).
- You're not checking `f.WriteString` error response.
- It *is* possible to open a named pipe as a file like you're doing, but it's better to use [`winio.DialPipe`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/microsoft/go-winio@v0.3.4#DialPipe), which is designed for this purpose.
- On the server you're trying to print the buffer when `err != nil` instead of when `err == nil`.
- You're creating a string from the entire buffer, but you should use the number of bytes returned from `Read`, as it can (will) be less than the buffer size.

See corrected code below.

**The server:**

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"

    "github.com/Microsoft/go-winio"
)

func handleClient(c net.Conn) {
    defer c.Close()
    log.Printf("Client connected [%s]", c.RemoteAddr().Network())

    buf := make([]byte, 512)
    for {
        n, err := c.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                log.Printf("read error: %v\n", err)
            }
            break
        }
        str := string(buf[:n])
        log.Printf("read %d bytes: %q\n", n, str)
    }
    log.Println("Client disconnected")
}

func main() {
    pipePath := `\\.\pipe\mypipename`

    l, err := winio.ListenPipe(pipePath, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", err)
    }
    defer l.Close()
    log.Printf("Server listening op pipe %v\n", pipePath)

    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("accept error:", err)
        }
        go handleClient(conn)
    }
}
```

**And the client:**

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/Microsoft/go-winio"
)

func main() {
    pipePath := `\\.\pipe\mypipename`
    f, err := winio.DialPipe(pipePath, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening pipe: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    n, err := f.Write([]byte("message from client!"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("write error: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println("wrote:", n)
}
```